# I cannot split an string with IFS command

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new at Bash. I couldn't solve this problem. I want to find and delete empty files. I can't get the file names correctly.
When I use the following commands, empty_files gets empty file names.

```
$ empty_files=$(find ./ -name "*.txt" -size 0k)
$ echo EMPTY_FILES:$empty_files;
EMPTY_FILES:./e2.txt ./e1.txt ./subdir/se1.txt
```

After, I want to split the empty_files and send to empty_files_splitted array.

```
$ IFS=' ' read -ra empty_files_splitted <<< "$empty_files"
```

But, when I run the IFS command, it pass only one file name. There is only one value at empty_files_splitted array. Why?

```
$ echo ${empty_files_splitted[0]}
./e2.txt
```

I try to split with space, am I wrong?
How can I do it?

Comment: The string is separated by newlines, not by spaces. Check `echo EMPTY_FILES:"$empty_files"`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look.

Comment: At a bash prompt, type `help mapfile` -- that's the way you read lines of output into a bash array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `read` section of `bash` man page states:

> read - One line is read from the standard input,

Therefore the code

```
IFS=' ' read -ra empty_files_splitted <<< "$empty_files"
```

just reads the the 1st line `./e2.txt` and assigns `empty_files_splitted` to it, then the remaining lines are discarded.

If you want to assign the array properly, please try instead:

```
readarray -t empty_files_splitted <<< "$empty_files"
```

BTW it is not recommended to hold the result of `find` as a newline-separated value in a
scalar variable because some filenames may include newline characters.

It will be safer to say something like:

```
while IFS= read -r -d "" f; do
    empty_files_splitted+=("$f")
done < <(find ./ -name "*.txt" -size 0k -print0)
```

It may not be easy to grasp what is going on here but you'll be understanding it
soon if you enjoy writing bash.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks your answer.. I learned that using IFS in bash this way causes problems. I tried the following solution. I access file names from sh file. No problem for now.

find -name "* .txt" -size 0k> empty_files.sh

Answer (score 0):

When you read into an array (read -a ...), bash will populate array[0], array[1], .... You can iterate over the elements using ${array[*]}, or ${array[@]}.

For you example to work:

> echo ${empty_files_splitted[@]}

If you just want to delete empty files, and no need for additional processing, you can use `find` ability to execute commands. (-empty is a shortcut for -size 0)

```
find ./ -name "*.txt" -size 0K -delete

# OR using -empty test instead of -size
find . -name '*.txt' -delete

# To print and delete
find . -name '*.txt' -delete -print
```

Comment: Thanks for the find shortcuts, I didn't use them because I'll do different checks.  I'm sorry, I looked at this command (echo ${empty_files_splitted[@]}), again there is only one element, it is in the 0 index, others are empty. I think, problem is in spaces.

Comment: It's possible, (and likely) the $empty_files is new lines (and not spaces) between files. Try using `echo "EMPTY_FILES:$empty_files"` to find if this is the case. Consider piping the output if 'find' directly into the `while read` loop, without the intermediate storage into a variable.